# How to convert radius in meters to pixels to draw circle without using Google API?

Tags: android, pixel, geometry, meter

I need to draw a circle with radius 300 meters with center at the center of the screen. To convert the meters to pixels.

I have searched and found

```
public static int metersToRadius(float meters, MapView map, double latitude) {
    return (int) (map.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(meters) * (1 / Math
            .cos(Math.toRadians(latitude))));
}
```

this to be a solution. Suppose i dont have the option to include the Google MapView API ,can this solution be implemented by using getProjection() from a source other than the Google API.

Comment: Are you drawing this circle on a map (with a known scale factor)? Or did you really mean a 300 m radius circle on huge Android screen (in which case you want to get its dpi)?

Comment: I am drawing it using canvas.drawCircle() and I have a zoom factor/level and drawing it on a normal mobile device.

Comment: It looks like you're drawing some custom maps. But only you know what scale that map is. See how many pixels you need on that map that represent a distance of 300m and you will know what your circle radius is.

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve velis. Is there a non Google API method that can help me in finding out the conversion from meters to pixels?

Comment: @AngelaSim you just have to do the math. The math depends on your map's zoom factor (scale), its projection (e.g. mercator), and latitude (since projecting a spherical globe onto a flat map has to stretch different latitudes to different amounts). You haven't provided enough information for us to do the math for you, but you can read up on it. The most commonly used projection used is mercator, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection